# How remove block in dxf file?

Tags: c#

How remove block in dxf file format?

---

I want to do this to "change in dxf file structure"
this means I want "remove block in dxf file programmatically"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To remove a block from your .dwg you must first delete all instances of the block. Then remove the block using the purge command."

http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?t=16470

Answer (score 1):

For removing things programmatically from a DWG file you will need a commercial library that provides programmatic access. There are a couple of these, have a look at e.g. [CadLib](http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.html) if you're using C# or VB.NET. If you're using C++, I can recommend the libraries from the Open Design Alliance (they do have .NET wrappers as well nowadays).